# Seemingly trivial class example will not compile

Tags: crystal-lang

I am attempting to configure properties of a specific type and guaranteed not to be nil with getters. This works fine for `String` or `URI` instance variables, however when attempting to do the same thing with an `HTTP::Client` the compiler gives an error that the instance variable is not initialized in all initialize methods.

```
require "http/client"

class Server
  getter uri : URI
  getter foo : String
  getter connnection : HTTP::Client

  def initialize(@uri)
    @foo = "Bar"
    @connection = HTTP::Client.new @uri
  end
end
```

The full error given by the compiler is:

```
Error in src/server.cr:6: expanding macro

  getter connnection : HTTP::Client
  ^

in macro 'getter' expanded macro: macro_4613328608:113, line 4:

   1.       
   2.         
   3.           
>  4.             @connnection : HTTP::Client
   5. 
   6.             def connnection : HTTP::Client
   7.               @connnection
   8.             end
   9.           
  10.         
  11.       
  12.     

instance variable '@connnection' of Server was not initialized directly in all of the 'initialize' methods, rendering it nilable. Indirect initialization is not supported.
```

How can I appropriately initialize the `@connection` instance variable so that the crystal compiler is happy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo there:

```
require "http/client"

class Server
  getter uri : URI
  getter foo : String
  getter connnection : HTTP::Client
  #          ^

  def initialize(@uri)
    @foo = "Bar"
    @connection = HTTP::Client.new @uri
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. As pointed out above you have a typo, so it's probably not even necessary to allow it to be nilable.

```
require "http/client" 

class Server 
  getter uri : URI 
  getter foo : String 
  getter connection : HTTP::Client? 

  def initialize(@uri) 
    @foo = "Bar" 
    @connection = HTTP::Client.new @uri 
  end 
end 

Server.new(URI.parse("https://www.google.com"))
```